# Sync multiple collections (in MongoDB Atlas database) to the mobile end via Realm sync

Tags: swift, mongodb, synchronization, realm

Inside the MongoDB Atlas database has 3 collections. Two collections have a one-to-many relationship and the third one does not have any relationship.

Can I use one Realm application to sync these 3 collections?

If this is possible, how to configure the Realm application inside the MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: Oh and *Can I use one Realm application to sync these 3 collections?* - yes you can.